# Line integral method calculate work done by a particle

Tags: vectors, line-integrals

I'm having trouble knowing how to go about solving this question:

Q:  The force on a particle at a point with position vector $r = xi + yj + zk$ exerted by a charge at the origin is $F(r)=\left(\frac{P(r)}{|r|^2}\right)$
in which P is constant. Calculate the work done as the particle moves in a straight line from (1, 0, 0) to (1, 2, 3).

What I think I need to do:

 $r_1=i$, $\quad$ $r_2=i+2j+3k$ $\quad$ so let $r(t)=i+2tj+3tk$,$\quad$ $0\lt t \lt 1$ 
 
Then $\frac{dr}{dt}=2+3=5$ and $|r|^2=1+13t^2$ 
Therefore, $$F(r)=\frac{P(i+2tj+3tk)}{1+13t^2}$$
As such, $\int_C F(r) \cdot dr=\int_0^1 \frac{P(i+2tj+3tk)}{1+13t^2} \cdot5 dt=\int_0^1 \frac{5P(1+5t)}{1+13t^2}dt=5P\int_0^1 \frac{1+5t}{1+13t^2}dt$ 
Is this the right way to go about answering this question, or am I doing something completely wrong? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $r(t)=(1,2t,3t)$ and $r'(t)$ is also a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work is computed as the line integral:

$$
\int_C F(r)\cdot dr = \int_0^1 F(r(t))\cdot r'(t) dt = \int_0^1 \frac{P}{1+4t^2+9t^2} (1,2t,3t)\cdot(0,2,3) dt = \int_0^1 \frac{13 P \,t}{1+13t^2}dt
$$

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense thanks. One thing I don't get though is why there is no P in the last integral, shouldn't it be 13Pt as the numerator of the integral?

Comment: Gone with the wind... I'll edit the post!